# Code review tool with mercurial support

Tags: code-review, mercurial

We currently use Review Board for code reviews, but over the last year I've found new releases increasingly buggy. Especially since upgrading to version 2.x, it seems mercurial support isn't getting much testing and it has resulted in users getting frustrated by random errors like the diff viewer throwing exceptions, and uploading diffs via the web interface not working (apparently everyone should be using RBTools) - support for specifying parent diffs was even removed.

I know Review Board is a popular tool, but I was wondering if anyone knew if there was a better alternative which supports mercurial?  I've not *used* it yet, but from what reading I've done Phabricator sounds good - almost too good to be true.  Since we've been using Review Board in our department for 3-4 years and now have thousands of reviews, there's a large resistance to change, and I'd like to try to ensure we'd not be jumping from the frying pan into the fire with any change.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We need some more details to give good recommendations here. Especially, could you please [edit] your question and explicitly list your requirements? See [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) and [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) for some closer hints. Thanks a lot, and good hunting!

Comment: Do you know if Review Board is having the same problems with other version control systems? If it is working well with, say, Git, would it be worth considering keeping Review Board and switching to Git? (I'm not suggesting it is, just checking all the options.)

Comment: The developers primarily vcs _is_ Git, so I think it should work much better than Mercurial.

Answer (score 1):

Having found http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_code_review I see there aren't many options! It's Phabricator, Review Board or Crucible. We do use other Atlassian products so it may be feasible to use Crucible, but it looks too expensive considering we're currently using a free tool. It looks like the best idea will be to set up a test installation of Phrabricator and let people try it out.

Comment: I don't know if the list has expanded since you posted this, or if you are limiting yourself to other criteria besides "must work with Mercurial". (Perhaps you are excluding "post-commit" workflow?) Not that there are a huge number of choices still.

Answer (score 1):

[Collaborator](http://smartbear.com/product/collaborator/specifications/) has support for Mercurial and many other version control systems.   I'm guessing for you cost might be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider checking out [Deveo](https://deveo.com). It supports hosting Git, Subversion, and Mercurial repositories. In addition, you can conduct code reviews using both Git and Mercurial. Code reviews can be conducted using Mercurial branches or bookmarks. The following blog post explains the basic workflow: http://blog.deveo.com/mercurial-code-reviews/

In addition to basic code review workflow, Deveo integrates to CI tools, such as [Jenkins](http://blog.deveo.com/jenkins-integration-to-feature-branch-workflow/) and [TeamCity](http://blog.deveo.com/teamcity-integration-to-feature-branch-workflow-2/), which you can bind to your code review flow. It's paid software but offers a 45-day free trial. Deveo can be used either from the cloud or hosted on your hardware.

(Disclaimer: I work at Deveo)